# Generate DataList at runtime containing a Div

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a DataList code which generates Div at run-time. This code was suggested by someone in one of my previous question:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="NamesDL" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="header">
       <%# Eval("Category") %>
    </div>
    <div class="Details">
       <%# Eval("CategoryDetails") %>
    </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
```

This is limited to one DataList control. I want to generate several DataList controls at run-time and want to display on each tab page of the AJAX Tab container. I also want to generate the Div dynamically.

I have a loop and I have a a slight idea:

```
for (int i=0; i<=3; i++)
{
    DataList DL = new DataList();
    Controls ctl = new Control();

    DL.Conrols.Add(ctl);
}
```

I am not following how to include the Div with each dynamically generated Div. The DataList will fetch the columns for the Div via a DataSource.

I want the code to be compatible with .NET 3.5.

Comment: you can create a custom control with a Panel and datalist..and then  wrap the datalist in to the Panel.

Comment: See the loop code I posted. The DataList is there, the control is there. I want to know how to insert DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `asp:Repeater`.

```
<asp:Repeater id="NamesDL" runat="server">

    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="header">
            <%# Eval("Category") %>
        </div>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="Details">
            <%# Eval("CategoryDetails") %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        <!--if you have other stuff, add it here-->
    </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Then bind your DataList to the Repeater.